# NoClassDefFoundError when running spray-can

Tags: scala, akka, spray, spray-routing

I have a multi-module sbt project which uses spray-can as one of its dependencies. Here is what I have in my sbt:

```
"com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.0",
"io.spray" % "spray-routing" % 1.2.0,
"io.spray" % "spray-can" % 1.2.0,
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.11",
```

I use scala version 2.11.6 and Java 8. When I run my project, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught error from thread [my-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[my-actor-system]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: spray/can/HttpManager$$anonfun$receive$1
    at spray.can.HttpManager.receive(HttpManager.scala:42)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:558)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:578)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.finishCreate(FaultHandling.scala:136)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.faultCreate(FaultHandling.scala:130)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.faultCreate(ActorCell.scala:369)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.faultRecreate(FaultHandling.scala:59)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.faultRecreate(ActorCell.scala:369)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:459)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
16:04:22.382 [my-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] ERROR akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught error from thread [my-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: spray/can/HttpManager$$anonfun$receive$1
    at spray.can.HttpManager.receive(HttpManager.scala:42) ~[spray-can-1.2.0.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:558) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:578) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.finishCreate(FaultHandling.scala:136) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.faultCreate(FaultHandling.scala:130) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.faultCreate(ActorCell.scala:369) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.faultRecreate(FaultHandling.scala:59) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.faultRecreate(ActorCell.scala:369) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:459) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
Uncaught error from thread [inland24-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped to solve my issue:

```
"io.spray" %% "spray-routing" % sprayVersion,
"io.spray" %% "spray-can" % sprayVersion,
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % akkaVersion,

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

val sprayVersion = "1.3.3"
val akkaVersion = "2.3.9"
```